# How to find maximum value in a list of arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large list of arrays that looks something like this:

```
'apples': array([1,2,3,4]), 'pears': array([1,2,10,11]),'oranges': array([1,10,10,3])
```

I want to find the maximum value out of all the arrays. In my short example above it would be 11.

I am struggling to write something that would give me the maximum value for all arrays in the list. Any thoughts would be welcome.

Comment: i think it would be 11

Comment: That looks more like a dict of arrays than a list.

Comment: short on curlies, though

Comment: Is `array()` is not producing error to you like `TypeError: array() argument 1 or typecode must be char (string or ascii-unicode with length 1), not list
` @AlexTrevylan

Answer (score 2):

Your list is actually a dictionary, so you can do this:

```
arr = {'apples': [1,2,3,4], 'pears': [1,2,10,11],'oranges': [1,10,10,3]}
res = max(map(max, arr.values()))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
11
```

You can also do it using the `chain` function from `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import chain

arr = {'apples': [1,2,3,4], 'pears': [1,2,10,11],'oranges': [1,10,10,3]}
res = max(chain(max(i) for i in arr.values()))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
11
```

Comment: Thank you - however, when I run this I get: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Did you format your list like I did? Because it is a dictionary not a list. Try using the my `arr` declaration.

Comment: You can replace `lambda i: max(i)` with just `max`: `res = max(map(max, arr.values()))`

Comment: @PaulPanzer thank you for notifying me. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

would this work?

```
big_dict = {"apple" : list([1,2,3]),
            "pear" : list([4,5,6])}

print max([max(v) for v in big_dict.itervalues()])
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example given it looks like that's a dictionary rather than a list, anyways for simplicity let's assume that it is a list in the form of:

```
[[2,3,55],[23,5,63],[2,3,6],[4,6,78], ...]
```

So what you can do is iterate over the main list and keep the current max value in a variable, and just compare to max of each array and update if greater.

**Example**

```
max_value = 0
for l in yourList:
    curr = max(l)
    if curr > max_value:
        max_value = curr
print max_value
```

This can be easily converted to use dictionary instead of a list, just iterate over each of the items within the dictionary and the logic would be the same (would have to get `max()` from the value).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think max is not a callable here because max is your variable containing integer value.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a dictionary variable d, then give this a try

```
l=[max(d[key]) for key in d.keys()]
print max(l)
```

Or you can use a one liner

```
print max([max(d[key]) for key in d.keys()])
```

Comment: List comprehension will just reduce your code to 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

you can't directly do that, try to form a another array and check 'max(arraylist)'

Answer (score 0):

First create a new list that contains the max values from each dictionary element then get the max of that new list

```
dict = {"apples" : [1, 2, 8, 4], "fruits": [3,2,6]} 

maxlst = [max(el) for el in dict.values()]
print(max(maxlst))
```

Answer (score 0):

The more pythonic way for me is to use comprehension dicts :

```
dictionary = {'apples': np.array([1,2,3,4]), 
'pears': np.array([1,2,10,11]),'oranges': np.array([1,10,10,3])}

In [144]: { k:v.max() for k,v in dictionary.items() }
Out[144]: {'apples': 4, 'oranges': 10, 'pears': 11}
```

An other easy way is to use pandas :

```
In [145]: pd.DataFrame(dictionary).max()
Out[145]: 
apples      4
oranges    10
pears      11
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like below, for large list

```
obj={'apples': [1,2,3,4], 'pears': [1,2,10,11],'oranges': [1,10,10,3]}

max(sum(obj.values(), []))

11
```

Comment: Thanks sanket - I am using pandas - when I print my data frame it is printed with the array declaration

Comment: ohhh you just added `python` as a tag, thats why not understood